# Xpress Mosel Parallel Solving

Tags: parallel-processing, mosel, xpress-optimizer

Is it possible to have two submodles (.mos) running in parallel as input data for a master problem?

Is it correct to repeat twice the next code, one for each sub model? Because I have one bim file for each sub model, in my case 2 bim files.

declarations
A = 1..10
modPar: array(A) of Model
end-declarations

if compile("rtparams.mos")<>0 then exit(1)
end-if

forall(i in A) do
load(modPar(i), "rtparams.bim")
run(modPar(i), "PARAM1=" + i)
end-do

forall(i in A) do
wait
dropnextevent

end-model

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should work. However, it is probably better to not just drop the event but capture it (via [getnextevent](https://www.fico.com/fico-xpress-optimization/docs/latest/mosel/mosel_lang/dhtml/getnextevent.html)) and then check the type exit status/code to make sure the submodel did not stop with an error.

You have detailed examples for this in the user manual [here](https://www.fico.com/fico-xpress-optimization/docs/latest/mosel/UG/dhtml/moselugD3_sec_secD3par.html).

Basically, what you do instead of `dropnextevent` is this:

```
 event:=getnextevent
 writeln("Exit status: ", getvalue(event))
 writeln("Exit code  : ", getexitcode(modPar(i)))
```

(and then of course handle errors).